# DatePicker, Having A Range or Selecting Date Causes View To Shift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an odd issue where my view is being shifted down on a DatePicker that has the style `GraphicalDatePickerStyle()`. The things I've noticed are that if you have a minimum range added, in my case `Date()` it will flicker after a moment or two and shift downwards. I have also noticed if I remove that, it doesn't happen until the moment when I actually select a date on the picker itself. Here is a gif of that happening. In this example, I have removed the minimum selectable date.

[image]

The way that this view is being presented is via `.offset` modifier on the main view. This view is always present, though not visible and when you tap the add button it sets the `offset` back to `0`. I stripped 99% of everything out and I still can't identify the problem.

### Presentation Code (Minimal Reproducible, I Think)

```
struct TimeListView: View {
@ObservedObject var vm = TimerListViewModel()
@State var showsAddModal = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach (vm.events) { dueDate in
                    CountdownView(dueDate: dueDate)
                        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                }
            }
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .background(Color.promptlyLightNavy)

        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                showsAddModal.toggle()
            }
        }, label: {
                Text("+")
                    .font(.custom("system", size: 50))
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    .foregroundColor(.promptlyNavy)
                    .padding(.bottom, 7)
            })
            .background(
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.promptlyTeal)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3))
            .padding()

        Rectangle()
            .fill(showsAddModal ? Color.promptlyNavy.opacity(0.8) : .clear)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation { showsAddModal.toggle() }
        }

        if showsAddModal {
            AddCountdownView(dismissed: {
                withAnimation { showsAddModal.toggle() }
            }, add: { date, title in
                vm.addEvent(event: Event(date: date, title: title))
            }).transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

### View That Is Causing The Problem (Minimal Reproducible)

```
struct AddCountdownView: View {
var dismissed: () -> ()
var add: ((date: Date, title: String)) -> ()

@State private var eventDate = Date.now
@State private var eventTitle = ""

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
        Spacer()
        
        VStack {
            Divider()
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.promptlyOrange)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 4)
            
            TextField("", text: $eventTitle)
                .placeholder(when: eventTitle.isEmpty, placeholder: {
                Text("Event Title").foregroundColor(.promptlyLightTeal)
            })
                .underlineTextField()
                .font(.title)

            

            DatePicker("asdf",selection: $eventDate, in: Date()...)
                .applyTextColor(.white)
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            
            HStack(spacing: 50) {

                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation { dismissed() }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .font(.title)
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .fill(Color.promptlyTeal)
                                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                                .frame( height: 50)
                        )
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    add((date: eventDate, title: eventTitle))
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.seal")
                        .font(.title)
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .fill(Color.promptlyTeal)
                                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                                .frame( height: 50)
                        )
                })

            }
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(.promptlyNavy)
        }
        .background(Color.promptlyNavy)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 0, y: -3)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related directly to the way that DatePicker handles it's coloring. In my problem I was attempting to set the color by using a `Hacky` solution provided by a bunch of other people.

### Hacky Solution (That's Bugged on iOS 15.X)

This is only bugged in this particular situation, where there's also a shadow added the the parent view.

```
@ViewBuilder func applyTextColor(_ color: Color) -> some View {
    if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
        self.colorInvert().colorMultiply(color)
    } else {
        self.colorMultiply(color)
    }
}
```

### Proper Solution (iOS 15.X)

```
DatePicker("asdf", selection: $eventDate, in: Date()...)
    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    .accentColor(.promptlyOrange) // Sets Accent Color
    .colorScheme(.dark) //Gets The white text.
```